# how to refreshing datatables jquery when manually updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

when you use jquery.tablesorter, and you manually update the `table` html, for example, append a `tr` element to the body

```
$("table tbody").append("<tr><td class='center'>value1</td><td>value2</td></tr>");
```

you can call

```
$('table').trigger("update");
```

and all works ok, now, i'v been asked to use jquery.datatables, and i'm trying to do the same but no result, i'm thinking to use the `fnAddData` function, but, what about if a need a css class in a `td` for styling like in the example above??, exist somthing in `DataTables` like the update of `tablesorter`??

need some help here

Comment: try adding this option `bDestroy":true`

Comment: ok, i'll give it a try, can you tell me where i can find a full list of the options i can pass to datatables when initializing?

Comment: ok, the full list is here http://datatables.net/ref thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lots of test, this was my final solution to what i was trying to do, first, append the html to the table `tbody`, then call `fnDestroy` and `dataTable` again, this do exactly what i wanted

```
var a = $("table").dataTable();
$("table tbody").append("<tr><td class='center'>value1</td><td>value2</td></tr>");
a.fnDestroy();
a.dataTable();
```

hope its help someone else in the future